# glLoadIdentity replace which matrix?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, jogl

```
public void render(GL2 gl) {
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW); 
gl.glLoadIdentity();
glu.gluLookAt(2.0, 7.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
gl.glRotated(rotate, 0,0,1);
gl.glTranslated(-3, 0, -3);
glut.glutSolidCube(1);
}
```

I know the loadIdentity means replace **current** matrix with the identity matrix. But it is not clear to me. Here is my analysis. I know it must be wrong, but I can't figure it out why.

opengl is a state-machine using stack.So the code above

first draw cube

then translate(-3,0,-3)// matrix T1

then rotate()//matrix R1

so current matrix is T1R1

then loadIdentity and the current matrix will be identityMatrix.

I know it is definitely wrong. Can someone explains?

Comment: Why are you going backwards in code with your reasoning?

Comment: @mrVoid because opengl works backwards? I just want to simulate how the opengl process.

Comment: Only the matrix combining work backward because of the order of Matrix * Vertex operations. Its the opposite in DirectX. But still the all of the code flow follows general rules of code execution - keeping in mind the state.

Comment: @AlexWei: OpenGL is not a stack machine. OpenGL has a state, but the only stacks there used to be are the legacy fixed function matrix and attrib bit stacks. However you have to explicitly push and pop them. However your code snippet never manipulates the stack and thing just happen in order. Also in modern OpenGL the stacks have been removed, along with all the built in matrix manipulation stuff.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks a lot. I just learned the fixed function. I will do more reading about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a construct like that:

```
class GL2 {
 int currentMatrix;
 mat44 matrices;

 glMatrixMode(matIdx) {
  currentMatrix = matIdx;
 }

 glRotated(r, x, y, z) {
   matrices[currentMatrix] *= mat44.createRotationMatrix(r,x,y,z);
 } 

 glTranslated(x, y, z) {
   matrices[currentMatrix] *= mat44.createTranslationMatrix(x,y,z);
 }
}
```

This is obviously fake but it gives you an idea that the GL state machine acctualy stores the state of the current matrix somwhere. It is not a stack - I think you might be refering to glPush and glPop for stack operations. This is not the case here.

So in your code:

1. Use the modelview Matrix
2. Set the modelview Matrix to identity
3. Multiply the modelview Matrix by LookAt Matrix construct
4. Multiply the modelview Matrix by Rotation Matrix
5. Multiply the modelview Matrix by Translatio Matrix
6. Feed verticles to openGL -> will be transformed by the current Matrix state